# How to free memory created by malloc after using execvp?

Tags: c, linux, exec

In my C program, I create a child process and in it, it parses a string and created a pointer array (using `malloc()`) for the use of passing it in `execvp()` command.

But the problem is, how do you free the memory that the child created? `execvp()` runs the new task and may or may not return. If it doesn't return, then it was successful and the child dies (and I can't really use the `free()` command). If it failed then it returned, then it continues doing the next lines of code, is this the only chance to free the memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to.  Specifically, if you allocate memory in a process before an `exec()`-type routine (e.g., `execvp()` in your case) is called, all of the memory associated with the original executable is released.  It's a similar situation to a process exiting (and having all its resources released), and a new process being started with a clean slate.

Comment: And this is documented in http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html